# Compare the field values in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing

i have two collection A and B
for A contains

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fb2143af31dfd122ce39c4b"),
  "Name" : "Freelander 2.2D",
  "Manufacture" : "Landrover"
}
```

and  B ,

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fb21439f31dfd122ce39c4a")      
  "Name" : "Rangerover",
  "Manufacture" :  "Landrover",

}
```

let me know how to check field values same(here it is "Name" have different values) for A and B  in C# driver .If it finds differences i need to update too

Please shed some light on this,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't do queries that involve more than one collection. One query - one collection, period.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Sergio is mostly right (I can't see a way to do this using a language driver), but it is possible using the shell:

```
var a_in_b = function(o){ 
   var numB = db.B.find({Name:o.Name}).count();
   if (numB > 0) print (o.Name + " is in both A and B");
} 

> db.A.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb2143af31dfd122ce39c4b"), "Name" : "Freelander 2.2D", "Manufacture" : "Landrover" }
> db.B.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb667d60569d84fec6ef57e"), "Name" : "Rangerover", "Manufacture" : "Landrover" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fb66a830569d84fec6ef57f"), "Name" : "Freelander 2.2D", "Manufacture" : "Landrover" }
> db.A.find().forEach(a_in_b);
Freelander 2.2D is in both A and B
```

If your requirement is an admin-related one, this might be what you're looking for.  If you're wanting to do this from the C# driver (like a SQL join, I guess), then no, you can't.